# How to build a classification pipeline that will pass to another model?

Tags: cnn, decision-trees, convolutional-neural-network

Not sure if the title explained it, but I am trying to build a pipeline where it's like a decision tree, but also not. Say for example, I had a picture. The model classified the picture, but now I want to send it to another CNN. How could I create something like this? Sorry if it's not detailed, still figuring it out!

Comment: What you want to pass the Image or the prediction from first model ?

Comment: @10xAI Both. Pass the image and prediction on to another classifier. So, for example,  put the image through, and use the first prediction to affect the second prediction (from the second classifier) to increase or decrease the probability of the correct classification.

Comment: This can be realized as a very simple _stacking ensemble_ (with just one base estimator), if I'm understanding your approach correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Microsoft Azure, to make two different pipelines. If I am not wrong, I understand that you want to compare the two methods, using a pipeline, therefore Microsoft Azure ML Studio is an easy and quick method to test your ideas.